# What is the meaning of Eternal Feather's braid writing Jesús Navas?

Tags: symbolism, soul-eater

In episode 08 of *Soul Eater! Not*:

> Eternal Feather is hospitalized and Stein createds a clone of her to mess with the girls. Her braid comes to life...

and leaves a message on the bedsheets:

[image: Picture from episode 08 of Soul Eater! Not: "Jesus Navas"]

[Jesús Navas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jes%C3%BAs_Navas) seems to be a soccer player for Manchester City. I don't follow football myself, but he doesn't seem to be particularly of note or any influence on Japanese pop culture.

Is this the person *Soul Eater! Not* is referring to? Why is it relevant?

Comment: If i was to guess, based off you line *"Her braid comes to life and leaves a message on the bedsheets"*, the comes to life part with the name makes me think it is supposed to be "Jesus of Nazareth" who we all know died then came back to life. Navas = Nazareth may be a way to try and censor religoin in the anime as in La Pucelle: Tactics when it was localized in the US [almost every instance of a cross was removed from the game](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/La_Pucelle:_Tactics#Release)

Comment: This happens in Chapter 16 of the [manga](http://i.stack.imgur.com/kLmt0.jpg) as well.